# Skia Drawing Text on Canvas not being aligned prorperly

Tags: fonts, skia

I'm trying to draw text on a Skia Canvas.  However, the text is never aligned properly.  I have looked over a few articles on the subject.  But drawing text without any modifiers I get the following results.  I have verified that they all have the same y position.

How do I get them aligned?

[image]

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the actual question here. Do you mean aligned horizontally, vertically or do you mean you want them to fit in the container object?

Comment: Turns out it is working as designed.